# How do I separate duplicated objects?

Tags: modeling

[image]

So when I started modelling this character, I duplicated her leg so that whatever i do with her left leg (in screenshot) is mirrored on the opposite end. Now I want to merge the pelvis, which requires me selecting the edges of both legs. So how do I separate both legs (Cube and Cube.001)?

Comment: Did you use "Alt D" to duplicate the leg as an instance or a mirror modifier?

Comment: Hello why don't you simply use a Mirror modifier?

Comment: We prefer using the mirror modifier rather than instances for that purpose. Instances are for populating, modifiers are for modeling. 
You can delete one of the legs, then add a mirror modifier on the other. So long your object origin is in the center, you probably do not need to ever apply it untill you need to model in asymmetry.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you used <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> which creates a linked duplicate of an object and copy's any geometry changes in both meshes. You can separate them by selecting on one of the legs, and then going to the *Object > Relations > Make Single User > Object & Data* menu option. Now you should be able to edit them seperately.

[image]